# How to create Blender Assets that have a built-in boolean intersect, i.e. windows that can be dropped to a wall with one click?

Tags: asset-browser, boolean-modifier

My goal is to create architectural elements in my Asset Browser that I can quickly drop from the Asset Browser onto a wall of a building to create custom buildings. I can create windows, doors etc. but I also have manually set up a boolean modifier so a recessed window would cut in the wall. With many elements, it's very tedious. Is there an automated, or easier way to do this?

Ideally, I would like to create a window, drop it onto a wall and it would automatically cut a hole in the wall, retaining the wall UVs and materials properly, and so that I won't have to select the boolean objects for every single window, door and other elements.

I'm aware of some architectural plugins that do that, but they don't work well for me, as I need a very specific material setups for my objects, and I need to model real-life buildings closely, so random seed generators won't work for me. I want basically to create a kit to speed up the work, but the boolean part slows me down...

Comment: Hello. You can look into this method https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEi1Otw7aG0

Answer (score 1):

Dropping an object to create a boolean wouldn't work because the mesh resulting from the boolean operation is contained within the object that holds the modifier, in that case that would be the house. Best I can figure is to create a geometry nodes modifier on the house object, taking a collection as input, connecting that collection to the mesh boolean node and put as many boxes in that collection as you need windows carved out (or whatever shape fits best).
To automate this further, for the windows you could have another geometry nodes modifier generating a window for you, which you could then drop into your scene's "boolean" collection to your heart content.